# Remove all Rows Programmatically from TableLayout

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

i use following code to remove rows out off my tablelayout;
System.out.println(vi); gives me 4 unique rows and thats right but why my loop is not removing all rows at once. I need to click  3 times.

This code is placed in myOnclickHandler;

```
   public void onClick(View v) { 

   TableLayout container = (TableLayout) v.getParent().getParent();

   int childcount = container.getChildCount();
   View vi;

   for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++) {

           vi = container.getChildAt(i); 
           container.removeView(vi);


          System.out.println(vi);
   }


 }
```

Comment: have you check childcount value ?

Comment: Try container.removeAllViews() instead.

Comment: yes so as i say i got 4 unique rows as result

Comment: yes this is working container.removeAllViews(); But i can't understand that if container.removeAllViews() removes all childs rows and after deletion i add fresh new Rows i got error message            java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must
call   removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
   row = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.row);
   table.removeView(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this it keep only header row.

```
if (table.getRootView() != null) {
    int i = 1;
    while (table.getChildCount() != 1) {
        table.removeViewAt(i);
    }
}
```